# $D_n$ is the number of derangements of $n$ objects, $P_n$ the number of permutations of $n$ objects with one fixed point. Find $D_{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let $D_n$ be the number of derangements of $n$ objects and $P_n$ be the number of permutations of $n$ objects with exactly one fixed point. How to find $P_n$ in terms of $D_{n-1}$?

After putting some thought into this I have come to the following conclusion:

Any permutation with exactly one fixed point must fix only one element of the $n$ total elements hence if we pick an element of the $n$ objects this number of ways to permute the other $n-1$ elements in the required way is $D_{n-1}$ now since we can pick the element in exactly $n$ ways we have $P_n=n\cdot D_{n-1}$.

Is this correct? If not why not?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.